# Cryptogram or Anagram

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, anagram

[image: Cryptogram or Anagram?]

> ```
> ArenETalagooD
>  fanemiPhOdl
> ```

Clues:

- The answer is 7 characters
- Answer can include the following characters: `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`

Ideas:

- I first used all characters adjacent to every capital letter and got: "rnaoihd", which could be an anagram for "hoardin", though it's not exactly a dictionary word~
- The puzzle maker follows a theme of being logical, mathematical, and (if applicable) involve popular literary references, though no it's not explicitly stated here. One idea was that this could be an anagram for "The Domain Of Edgar Allan Poe", referencing to "The Domain of Arnheim" by Edgar Allan Poe. Not sure on this one though..

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/cryptogames/comments/c0twrr/3_eth_challenge_puzzle_stored_on_a_permanent_and/)

Comment: The Poe anagram is likely correct. The letters in the puzzle can be rearranged to `The Domain Of Edgar Allan Poe`, with both the capital letters and the proper spelling of his middle name. How will you know when you've found the correct answer, though?

Comment: @codewarrior0 It's a part of a larger hosted on a website, check source!